# Wordpress isolate menu, when changing screen size

Tags: wordpress, menu, header

I have made a homepage for my fathers birthday. When changing screen size or using his ipad the header is collapsing on a header. If you try to change screen size on test.virumfarveogtapet.dk, you can see exactly what i mean.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you mean "menu" is appearing in ipad? instead for your original menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a CSS media query error. Try adding this CSS rule.

```
@media all and (max-width: 1026px) and (min-width: 767px){
    .elementor-element.elementor-element-6fcfdccd.elementor-widget.elementor-widget-heading {
        margin-top: 90px;
    }
}
```